# Format Entire Excel Column Using C#

Tags: c#, vsto

I have column F that I want to format as money so add $ sign and commas.  It's to late for me to attempt to format it in the Source so I was going to format it via C# after all data has been written to Excel.  I know you can use this syntax to change a column to a date - what would be the appropriate syntax for money?

> range.EntireColumn.NumberFormat = "MM/DD/YYYY";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for my stupidity on this one...it's actually quiet simple

> range3.EntireColumn.NumberFormat = "$#,##0.00";